# C# Entity access a List component by its number

Tags: c#, list, datatable, components, entity

good noon for all.

I has a next problem: Take data from DataBase
(C# NetFrameWork 5)

```
//Taka the List
     EDBRecList = f1.edb.fn_EDBRecipes().ToList();
//  Take the columns name
       var Colls = (from t in typeof(fn_EDBRecipes_Result).GetProperties() select t.Name).ToList();
           DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Clear();
            dt1.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (var c in Colls)
            {
                dt1.Columns.Add(c);
            }
//it`s OK
//but how to fill the table in a loop? referring to columns by their number
//now using the next long process

            for (int j = 0; j < EDBRecList.Count; j++)
            {
                NewString = new string[] {
                    EDBRecList[j].ID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].RecipeName,
                    EDBRecList[j].RecTypeID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].RecTypeName,
                    EDBRecList[j]. ProdID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].ProductCode,
                    EDBRecList[j].ProdName,
                    EDBRecList[j].ProductTypeID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].ProductSetID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].ProdGroupID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].ProducedMaterialID.ToString(),
                    EDBRecList[j].SystemName
                };

                

                dt1.Rows.Add(NewString);
            }
```

thank you in advance

the method works on 10 columns. what if there are 100 of them?

Comment: There are a gazillion of ToDataTable Extension Methods out there. One should fit for your fn_EDBRecipes types. An example that should be easy adaptable is https://csharp-extension.com/en/method/1002643/array-todatatable

Answer (score 0):

Just use reflection, as you did for getting the column names, and make use of that column name list of yours:

```
Type elementType = EDBRecList.GetType().GetElementType();

for (int j = 0; j < EDBRecList.Count; j++)
{
    NewString = (from col in Colls
                 select elementType.GetProperty(col).GetValue(EDBRecList[j], null).ToString()
                ).ToArray();

    dt1.Rows.Add(NewString);
}
```